# How to get local variable values from crash report in iOS

Tags: ios, logging, crash, crash-dumps

I am using Fabric/Crashlytics to get crash information for my iOS app. However most of the times, crash is because of an unexpected data. For instance, a crash could be caused by an extra space at the end of a string, or an integer being negative when my code didn't expect it to be.

How can I get values of such local variables, etc from my app crash reports?

This Link describes what I need (but for iOS) - http://www.ilikebigbits.com/blog/2016/2/28/error-context-better-logging-with

Comment: You can't. Crash reports don't provide any information about variable data, just a call stack.

Comment: I know. But I believe many developers would be facing this problem. There should definitely be some solution for this.

Comment: You can't so no, there is no solution for this in iOS.

Comment: This actually works with a sample program on Linux. How does it work there?